# How to sync AIO cooler to fan to motherboard

Tags: cpu, motherboard, power-supply, fan, cooling

I am pretty new to hardware and I’m currently trying to connect my AIO cooler with my other fans to the motherboard but unfortunately when I tried to change the RGB color, the fans and the cooler are not changing, but the RGB color of the motherboard is changing. Please see more details below.

Motherboard: Asrock B450M Steel Legend

AIO Cooler: Darkflash Twister DX-240 Ver.2

Fans: Darkflash C6MS 3-in-1 Aurora Spectrum

**What I did**

1. I connected the radiator to the addressable male pin
2. Connected the 3pin from cooler to CPU_FAN_1
3. Connected the 2 cables(4pins) to the hub, then connected the hub to motherboard 4pin male.
4. I connected the 3pins of the cooler fans to each other. As well as the 3-in-1 fan.

Please let me know if you need any information that is not indicated above.

Comment: The `Asrock Polychrome Sync` software should be able to control both sets of fans, have you installed, Asroc's RBG software?

Comment: @Ramhound Yup, I already installed that software. that’s actually the one im using. but the problem is that it only changing the color of rgb for motherboard

Answer (score 2):

Its in the [manual](https://download.asrock.com/Manual/B450M%20Steel%20Legend.pdf) - there's a seperate header for LED lighting you need plugged in.

[image]

Its either header 23 or 24.

You may need to cross reference that with the [fan manual](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GRsgDBJ3xq7alyddMh9ZlnBk-CXleQsl/view) for the correct header

[image]

Comment: it seems like the picture of the motherboard is different

Comment: .... I missed out the M - one sec

Comment: https://imageup.me/images/a0ad90f9-c52f-4752-9af8-93070e59fd4d.jpeg I took a picture of it. I already plugged the aio cooler then plugged the 3 fans on it

Comment: I can't really see if the ARGB or RGB headers are plugged in

Comment: Here another picture: https://imageup.me/images/f826f870-abdf-4d25-a041-485c887b2cc2.jpeg

Comment: And here’s another picture connected the aio cooler to the extension wire from motherboard https://ibb.co/ssnQhSz